# Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0) running on sdk-14.0.2 is not hitting debug breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

After years of Java development using Eclipse, I migrate to Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0) using sdk 14.0.2.  I am not able to hit a break point, essentially rendering this version worthless. Has anyone experienced this issue with this version? I would appreciate any information specific to this issue.  I have had a lot of experience with Eclipse. This issue is deeper than insuring the breakpoints are not disabled.

Comment: It's just you. A common mistake is to have a trigger point that is not hit (when a trigger point is not hit, none regular breakpoint will become active). Please show a screenshot of an editor containing a breakpoint that is not hit while debugging.

Comment: The issue was that after migrating to a newer version of Eclipse, I deployed a spring boot application as if was packaged as war file, when in fact it was an executable jar. As such, it deployed just fine but without debugging capability. Thanks for your responses.